# Website Track App Store Price

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore, price

I am looking or a website, which will monitor the price of an application on the Mac App Store and send me an email notification when the price of the application drops.

I have already tried [appspy.com](http://appspy.com), but they did not send me email when the price dropped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [App Shopper](http://appshopper.com). You need to register an account to utilize their price drop notification.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Store News](http://store-news-app.com) app ([Mac App Store preview](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/store-news/id416323139)).

No notification, but if you're interested in a particular app: you can create a smart filter, then it should be easy to see at a glance whether a change has occurred.

There's also a simplified [web interface to Store News](http://store-news-app.com/web/) but this doesn't allow creation of filters.